# Python: Removing an integer in a list within a list is removing the integer on all sublists lists

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

Here are my Variables:

- availableColorsForNode: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],[inf]]
- neighbor: 4
- availableColorsForNode[neighbor]: [1, 2, 3]
- adjacencyList: [[3], [2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2], [5], [4]]
- adjacencyList[node]: [4]
- color: 1

Here is the Code:

```
for neighbor in adjacencyList[node]:
    if color in availableColorsForNode[neighbor]: 
        availableColorsForNode[neighbor].remove(color)  #problem is here somehow
```

I am expecting:

- availableColorsForNode: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [inf]]

But I am getting (where 1 is removed everywhere):

- availableColorsForNode: [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [inf]]

Why is this happening? 
When I do a simple test such as the following I get the expected output:

```
test = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
test[4].remove(1)
print(test)
```

- output is [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

Comment: How did you create `availableColorsForNode` Could you show the code?

Comment: Here is how I set it up:    
colors = [i+1 for i in range(chromaticity)] #colors
availableColorsForNode = [colors] * len(adjacencyList)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i assume you set up your test more or like as

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

test = [lst, lst, lst, lst, lst]  # or: test = [lst] * 5
test[4].remove(1)
print(test)
```

`test` contains references to the *same* list now (instead of identical copies of the list). if you call `.remove` on any of them (e.g. `test[4].remove(1)`) the change will be reflected in all of them. because all the items in `test` still reference the same list `lst`.

here are four different suggestions on how you could fix this (if your list contains immutable data types you will not need `deepcopy`); i suggest you choose one of them and do not mix them; the code here is just to present the possibilities...:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

lst = [1, 2, 3]

test = [list(lst), lst[:], copy(lst), deepcopy(lst)]
test[2].remove(1)
print(test)
```

if you want that repeated, you could do this:

```
test = [lst[:] for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Amazing how you came up with the solution so quickly. Thank you so much. TIL

Comment: you are welcome! that is a very common thing to happen in python... please (upvote? and) accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I upvoted and accepted. By the way, the problem occurs when I try to initialize the list with a deep copy (I tried all 4 ways)
test3 = [deepcopy(lst)] * 6

So I can either loop through and append the manual way which will ensure it will work. But I was wondering if there was a simple way to instantiate a bunch of deep copied lists?

Comment: `[deepcopy(lst)] * 6` has the same problem... `deepcopy` is called once only. i suggest `test = [lst[:] for _ in range(6)]` (or similar). updated the answer.

Comment: Just for completeness: if the list contained mutable objects, you'd want `[deepcopy[lst] for _ in range(6)]` - else with `[lst[:] for _ in range(6)]` you'd have 6 different lists _but_ each containing the same objects so mutating any of those objects would yield unwanted results.